# To prevent groups to display as separate sheets in SSRS 2005 report exported as excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am designing reports using SSRS 2005.The exported reports in pdf format is coming fine but the problem is with the MS excel exported form where each  group in the tablix is getting displayed as a separate sheet.The requirement is that entire data must come in same sheet.Can you please help me in achieving this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon if you have page breaks within the report itself programmed, if you do it does separate onto separate tabs.  If you don't want to do this in Excel, you can use the following article as a reference for creating another parameter to handle the formatting for excel differently.

I read this was fixed in a later version of SSRS.

[Expoort To Excel Without Page Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061198/suppressing-page-breaks-upon-exporting-a-reporting-services-report-to-excel)

Edit:

You can try the below option with interactive setting.  As long as you do not have any page breaks specified it should work:

[Export to Excel on One Tab](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reportingservices/PFuTNKZ4jnk)

Comment: ,thanks for your reply.But the solution suggested in the link you provided works only from SSRS 2008R2 onwards and it doesn't work for SSRS 2005 :(

Comment: I edited the answer to have another option.  The first option I was not sure if it would work for 2005, but from what I can tell this might work for you.

Comment: I have page breaks in my report and it is necessary to have page break at the end of each group.